# Issue in the installation of the AWS CodeDeploy Agent in EC2 instance with AMI - Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04, aws-code-deploy

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance with AMI - Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (Free Tier) and try to install AWS CodeDeploy Agent into it.

I am following the official documentation from Amazon to install CodeDeploy agent into the Ubuntu server.[Documentation Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-ubuntu.html)

I have connected the EC2 instance with SSH Keypairs and run the following commands:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install ruby-full`

`sudo apt install wget`

`wget https://aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install`

`chmod +x ./install`

`sudo ./install auto`

In the last command, I got the following error message:

`I, [2022-11-25T20:22:45.262298 #4303]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.

E, [2022-11-25T20:22:45.262740 #4303] ERROR -- : **Current running Ruby version for root is 3.0.2, but Ruby version 2.x needs to be installed.**

E, [2022-11-25T20:22:45.262959 #4303] ERROR -- : **If you already have the proper Ruby version installed, please either create a symlink to /usr/bin/ruby2.x,**

E, [2022-11-25T20:22:45.263173 #4303] ERROR -- : **or run this install script with right interpreter. Otherwise please install Ruby 2.x for root user.**

E, [2022-11-25T20:22:45.263378 #4303] ERROR -- : You can get more information by running the script with --help option.`

Please let me know if there is any other hacks, I should employ to install AWS CodeDeploy agent in the EC2 instance with with AMI - Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (Free Tier).

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please edit your question again

Comment: The error is clear. You have to use ruby 2, not 3.